# Offsetof Function with std::vector

Tags: c++, data-structures

Could someone explain to me why the `offsetof` function does not work on std::vectors as shown below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct FooStruct {
    double x;
    double y[10];
    std::vector<double> z;
};
int main() {
    cout << offsetof(FooStruct, x) << endl;
    cout << offsetof(FooStruct, y[2]) << endl;
    cout << offsetof(FooStruct, z[2]) << endl;

    system("Pause");
}
```

Calling `offsetof(FooStruct, z[2])` produces the following compiling error:

`cannot apply 'offsetof' when 'operator[]' is overloaded`

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `offsetof` isn't a function but a macro, and only works on POD types, or standard layout class in C++11. It's only there for backward compatibility with C.

The reason the compiler refuses to allow you to use the subscription operator, all issues aside, is because the macro is evaluated at compile time, but the overloaded operator might do some work at runtime to calculate the result.

Answer (score 2):

`offsetof(FooStruct, z[2])` makes no sense.  The elements of `z` are not contained within a `FooStruct`, they're accessed via the `std::vector`, which has at its core a pointer to some other allocation on the heap within which `z[2]` can be found.

In any case, the error (which seems confusing I understand) is probably popping up because `std::vector` overloads `operator[]`, not because your `class FooStruct` overloads `operator[]` (which, assuming we see the whole definition, it doesn't).

If you want to find the offset of `z[2]` in relation to `z[0]`, you could just compute the difference between `&z[0]` and `&z[2]` like this:   `std::cout << (&z[2] - &z[0]) << '\n';`